# Converting Letters to Numbers

Tags: java

Let's say I have a program which converts letters to numbers such that:

Input: abcd

Output: 1234

1. How can I convert abcd to 1234 efficiently
2. and how can I extract every individual char from the token

By the way, this is not homework. (this is for fun)

This is what I have so far:

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {

    BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.in"));

    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("test.out.txt")));

    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(f.readLine());

    int i1 = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());

            // How can I convert this into integers? (where a = 1, b = 2, and c = 3)

            out.println(????);

        out.close();
        System.exit(0);                              

    }

}
```

Comment: Uppercase the letter, convert it to ASCII, subtract 'A', then add 1.

Comment: Your question needs a bit more specification.  For instance, what should 'wxyz' translate to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
String s = "abcd";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
    sb.append((char)(c - 'a' + 1));
}
// provided your string contains only lower case non-unicode (ASCII) characters.
```

Comment: not just fish, he gave him cooked fish served in the plate. :)

Comment: How does (c-'a'+1) work? So if c = 'b' than it is 'b'-'a'+1. How is that equal to 2?

Comment: because you can cast chars to int, a equals 97, b equals 98, then 98-97 = 1, (assuming a-a = 0)

Answer (score 1):

Have a map defined with keys as a,b,c etc with values 1,2,3 etc. Whenever you receive a token take that from the map and print.

Answer (score 1):

Uppercase the letter, convert it to ASCII, subtract 'A', then add 1.  If you're handling multi-character inputs, then iterate over the string.  As you calculate as per the previous recommendation, multiply the previous sum by 10, then add the new value.

Answer (score 0):

Derp, I read the whole question wrong. My bad.

What you could do, is that you have a conversion algorithm I suppose.
Each letter in the alphabet could have a value from the alphabet.

Then all you need to do, is match the letter you find, with a letter from you a string array, get it's index, and add 1 to it. Then you got the value. If that's how you wanna play.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is the method you are looking for: `String`'s [charAt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29)

A sample code that would do what you are after:

```
String a="abcd";
for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); ++i) {
   System.out.print(a.charAt(i)-'a'+1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try by convert the char to int and rest 96, you have to take care of out of range characters or use regex..

This sample converts abcd to 1234

a is the char with 97 (alt + 9 7)
z is the char 122

A is the char 65, so you can handle by ranges or just turn the word to lowercase

```
public static void main(String args[]){
        String abc = "abcd";
        String txt = "";

        for(int i=0; i<abc.length(); i++){
            txt+= ( (int)abc.charAt(i) - 96 );
        }

        System.out.println(txt);
    }
```

EDIT:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
        String abc = "AbCd";
        String txt = "";
        abc = abc.toLowerCase();

        for(int i=0; i<abc.length(); i++){
            int letter = (int)abc.charAt(i);

            if(letter<97 || letter > 122)//in range
            {
                txt += ( (int)abc.charAt(i) - 96 );
            }

        }

        System.out.println(txt);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class LetteredNumerationSystem{

```
public static void main(String args[]){

File file = new File ("lettered.in");

    try{

    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

    int dataCollect = input.nextInt();
    int sum=0;
    String lineInput ="";


      for(int i=0;i<=dataCollect;i++){
      while (input.hasNext()){
      lineInput=input.next();       
      char lineArray[] = lineInput.toCharArray();
         for(int j=0;j<lineArray.length;j++){
            if (lineArray[j] == 'A'){
              sum+=1;
            }
            else if (lineArray[j] == 'B'){
              sum+=10;
            }
            else if (lineArray[j] == 'C'){
               sum+=100;
            }
            else if (lineArray[j] == 'D'){
               sum+=1000;
            }
            else if (lineArray[j] == 'E'){
               sum+=10000;
            }
            else if (lineArray[j] == 'F'){
               sum+=100000;
            }
            else if (lineArray[j] == 'G'){
               sum+=1000000;
            }
            else if (lineArray[j] == 'X'){
               System.out.println(sum);
           sum=0;
            }
         }
        }
      }         
    }

    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("ERROR");
        }   




}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please explain what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.