# Converting Letters to Numbers 2

Tags: java

Refer to [Converting Letters to Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644420/converting-letters-to-numbers)

In the file `test.in.rtf`, I have 'abcd' typed. However, when I run the program, I get `??? ???????????  ???????? plus maybe a few more` in `test.out.rtf`. Why is this? Am I missing something?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {

        BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.in.rtf"));

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("test.out.rtf")));

        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(f.readLine());


        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (char c : st.nextToken().toCharArray()) {
            sb.append((char)(c - 'a' + 1));
        }

        out.println(sb);                           // output result
        out.close();                                  // close the output file
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

Comment: I am trying to convert letters to numbers where a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, z = 26...

Comment: debugging is part of the fun :)

Comment: RTF files are binary files.  You can't process them like string data.

Comment: @skaffman They're not binary. It's a markup language, which you could parse, it's just not very trivial.

Comment: @trutheality: Good point.  My mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you want

```
sb.append(Integer.toString(c - 'a' + 1));
```

or simply

```
sb.append( c - 'a' + 1 );
```

which implicitly does the same thing, since the expression `c - 'a' + 1` is implicitly cast to an `int` since Java does all non-`long` integer math (anything involving `char`s, `byte`s, `short`s, and/or `int`s) by converting everything to `int`s first.

What you had cast the integer result to a `char`, which would be represented by the character whose ASCII value is that number (something b/w 1 and 26), which isn't something readable.

Comment: No, I get 27-418206-47-4114199-41141993167-47-46-43-46-4315315118206-47-48-45-40-431531511921218206-45-43-48 somehow.

Comment: Is `test.in.rtf` a [Rich Text Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) file by any chance? Because this will only work for a text file.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to write the char values 1,2,3 and 4 ('a'-'a' + 1 = 1 and so on), which are all "unwriteable" hence the "?"s. Why you get 7 and not 4? I don't know - maybe a locale issue or 3 of them are just written as two "?".